# Django - VSCode does not recognize foreign key related names and gives error

Tags: django, visual-studio-code

Post model has a foreign key to User model with `posts` as its related name.

```py
posts = user.posts.all()
             ^^^^^
```

Django works fine obviously. But the error in VSCode is annoying.
How can I make VSCode know this is not an error?

Answer (score 1):

So this is a hack and will improve in the future, but this is the way to solve this right now (outside the mypy plugin, i.e in VS codes built in checker)

```
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from django.db.models.manager import RelatedManager


class RelModel(Model):
    belongs_to = models.ForeignKey(MyModel, related_name="things")


class MyModel(Model):       
    if TYPE_CHECKING:
        things: RelatedManager[RelModel]
```